# save user to row from frosuserbundle

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle

I got the following error:

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Rowoco\AllgemeinBundle\Entity\Place::setIdUser() must 
be an instance of Rowoco\AllgemeinBundle\Entity\FosUser, instance of   
Rowoco\UserBundle\Entity\User given, called in 
/var/www/symfony/src/Rowoco/AllgemeinBundle/Controller/AllgemeinAjaxController.php on line 64 and 
defined in /var/www/symfony/src/Rowoco/AllgemeinBundle/Entity/Place.php line 331
```

In the following function i try to add a new place:

```
public function test()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $stateRepo = $em->getRepository( "RowocoAllgemeinBundle:State" );
    $stateEntity = $stateRepo->find(1);

    $user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();

    $place = new Place();
    $place->setAdddate( "2014-01-01 12:12:10" );
    $place->setTitle( "test" );
    $place->setDescription( "testdescription" );
    $place->setSpecial( "special" );
    $place->setStreet( "strasse" );
    $place->setZipcode( "12345" );
    $place->setIdState( $stateEntity );
    $place->setIdUser( $user );



    $em->persist( $place );
    $em->flush();

    //return new Response('Created product id '.$product->getId());

    return true;
}
```

in the table place i have two foreignkeys

1. id_state
2. id_user

how can i fix this error?

Comment: Could you provide the code at `src/Rowoco/AllgemeinBundle/Entity/Place.php line 331`? The code in `Place` where you define the relationship with `User`, too.

Comment: The error message is telling you that Place::SetUserId expects a FOSUser and of course you are passing your User object.  So change the method signature.  Having said that, if you expecting to use Doctrine 2 ORM functionality then you really should have setUser vs setUserId.  Take a look at the Product/Category relation in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Somethings around your code:

- First the error is telling you what the problem is and where, take a look at this line:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Rowoco\AllgemeinBundle\Entity\Place::setIdUser() 
>   must be an instance of Rowoco\AllgemeinBundle\Entity\FosUser, instance of 
>   Rowoco\UserBundle\Entity\User

You're passing a complete object to `setIdUser()` method which BTW expect a `FOSUser` instance

- Second, if you're using Symfony > 2.1.x you should use `$this->getUser()` and not as you're doing (this is a tip)
- As third if you only need to insert the `id_user` as state in question, why pass the entire object? Why not just pass the current logged in user id? Something like `$this->getUser()->getId()`?